# web api combining attribute routing with convention-based routing does not work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Based on [documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

> Attribute routing can be combined with convention-based routing. To
>   define convention-based routes, call the MapHttpRoute method.

I want every route to start with `api`. For example i want the route to be `http://localhost:40000/api/client/{id}/batch/approve` so here is my WebApiConfig class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then in controller i have

```
public class BatchController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MyService _service;
    public BatchController(MyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("client/{id}/batch/approve")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Approve(int id, RequestDTO request)
    {
        return Ok(await _service.Approve(clientID,request).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
```

When client invoke this route, it receives `404 Not Found` response. 
However if i prefix `api` in Route attribute like below then it worked

```
    [Route("api/client/{id}/batch/approve")]
```

Why convention based routing not prefixing `api` to route, why i also need to explicitly add `api` prefix to Route attribute

Comment: Because they are completely separate routes in the route table. You can add a route prefix to the controller to avoid having to repeat it on the action s

Answer (score 0):

You must set `RoutePrefixAttribute` for the controller:

`[RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class BatchController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("client/{id}/batch/approve")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Approve(int id, RequestDTO request)
        {
            ...
        }
    }`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2